# Has anyone described etc. Ataraxia from not asking needless questions?

Tags: metaphilosophy, stoicism, hedonism

Has anyone described etc. Ataraxia from not asking needless questions? I am most familiar with the idea of ataraxy from Epicurus

> if one is frightened by the empty name of death, the fear will persist
> since we must all eventually die. This fear is one source of
> perturbation (tarakhê), and is a worse curse than physical pain
> itself; the absence of such fear is ataraxy, lack of perturbation, and
> ataraxy, together with freedom from physical pain, is one way of
> specifying the goal of life, for Epicurus.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epicurus/

Is there anything analogous in the calmness of knowing when a question should have been asked or should be asked? Quite how anyone can know what a good question is, I'm not sure. But that's not the question.

Comment: I guess you're about to find out if this question should have been asked.

Comment: well, i don't think not evoking an (easy) answer means something is a bad question, though YMMV @ScottRowe

Comment: As Epicurus already hinted ataraxia is not inconsistent or incompatible with physical pain thus if asking needless questions caused you pain nonetheless you could still be in ataraxia like the always skeptic Pyrrho's epoche if not like Epicurus. OTOH contrary to Epicurus' ideal practically speaking pain is unavoidable and even beneficial as biological self-defense mechanisms. Having said all that your perceived or conceived ataraxia is extremely subtle and hard to not to be affected by pains caused by various confusions and stuckedness from your own queried and motivated needless questions...

Comment: My brain is refusing to parse this question. Does the "etc." apply to "described?" My brain will thank you.